# Why am I getting error cant find method?

Tags: java, if-statement, queue

I am working on an assignment that requires me to use queues. A portion of the code comes straight out of my book, however I am getting several errors in my dequeue method of my ArrayUnbndQueue class.

```
public class ArrayUnbndQueue<T> implements UnboundedQueueInterface<T>
{
    protected final int DEFCAP = 100; // default capacity
    protected T[] queue;              // array that holds queue elements
    protected int origCap;            // original capacity
    protected int numElements = 0;    // number of elements in the queue
    protected int front = 0;          // index of front of queue
    protected int rear = -1;          // index of rear of queue

    public ArrayUnbndQueue()
    {
        queue = (T[]) new Object [DEFCAP];
        rear = DEFCAP - 1;
        origCap = DEFCAP;
    }

    public ArrayUnbndQueue(int origCap)
    {
        queue = (T[]) new Object[origCap];
        rear = origCap - 1;
        this.origCap = origCap;
    }

    private void enlarge()
    {
        T[] larger = (T[]) new Object[queue.length + origCap];

        int currSmaller = front;
        for (int currLarger = 0; currLarger < numElements; currLarger++)
        {
            larger[currLarger] = queue[currSmaller];
            currSmaller = (currSmaller + 1) % queue.length;
        }

        // update instance variables
        queue = larger;
        front = 0;
        rear = numElements - 1;
    }

    public void enqueue(T element)
    {
        if (numElements == queue.length)
            enlarge();
        rear = (rear + 1) % queue.length;
        queue[rear] = element;
        numElements = numElements + 1;
    }

    public T dequeue()
    {
        if (isEmpty())
            throws new QueueUnderflowException("Dequeue attempted on empty queue.");
        else
            {
              T toReturn = queue[front];
              queue[front] = null;
              front = (front + 1) % queue.length;
              numElements = numElements -1;
              return toReturn;
            }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return (numElements == 0);
    }

}
```

The public T deque method is exactly copied from my book.
The QueueUnderflowException class was not actually shown in my book so I was getting other errors in my interface and in this class, but I wrote the code for that

```
public class QueueUnderflowException extends RuntimeException
{
    public QueueUnderflowException()
    {
        super();
    }
    public QueueUnderflowException(String message)
    {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Netbeans gives me an error that it cant find method QueueUnderflowException, else with no if, and missing return statement.

I have tried to add brackets around the throws exception line, like the code below. This removes my "else with no if" error, and i could probably move the return statement to out side of the else statement, but I still get the can't find method error

```
public T dequeue()
        {
            if (isEmpty())
            {
                throws new QueueUnderflowException("Dequeue attempted on empty queue.");
            }
            else
                {
                  T toReturn = queue[front];
                  queue[front] = null;
                  front = (front + 1) % queue.length;
                  numElements = numElements -1;
                  return toReturn;
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`throws new QueueUnderflowException("Dequeue attempted on empty queue.");`

should be

`throw new QueueUnderflowException("Dequeue attempted on empty queue.");`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your  `public T dequeue()`

```
public T dequeue() {
  if (isEmpty())
  throws new QueueUnderflowException("Dequeue attempted on empty queue.");//throw 
                                                                     //not throws
  // this should be throw not throws
}
```

You are throwing exception from this `dequeue` method. To do this you need to have `throws` in method signature.

```
public T dequeue() throws QueueUnderflowException{
 throw new QueueUnderflowException("Dequeue attempted on empty queue.");
}
```

Comment: Actually, the throws clause is not required, since the OP declared QueueUnderflowException to extend RuntimeException.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether it will resolve all your erros but you need to use `throw` instead of `throws` in such statements:

```
            throws new QueueUnderflowException("Dequeue attempted on empty queue.");
```